# test function in Jest use wrong result from the other function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am very new to wrote the test file with Jest by my purpose is test that the applyPromotion function work as expect. Here is my code

```
describe('Promotion: Discount By', () => {
    let menu = [{id:1, name: menu A}, {id:2, name: menu B}]

    it('case 1', async () => { 
       var promotion = [{id:'P1', name:'promotion 1'}]
       var result = await applyPromotion(menu, promotion)
       expect(result['discountType']). toEqual('1')
    });

    it('case 2', async () => { 
       var promotion = [{id:'P2', name:'promotion 2'}]
       var result = await applyPromotion(menu, promotion)
       expect(result['discountType']). toEqual('2')
    });
})
```

Once I run the test, the result from 'case 2' return the result from 'case 1' instead.
I already change to use `mockReturnValueOnce` for result but it's not work too.

PS. I have another test file that have the same format like example above and it works very well.

Could you guys suggest me what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Since you haven't included how/where you have used `mockReturnValueOnce` it's really hard to imagine what you could have done wrong

Comment: At first, I thought it causes from the variable result isn't update. So, I try to use `mockReturnValueOnce` before get result. But actually, that's not the root cause :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer. the issue cause from the variable `menu` has been updated itself when it pass to `applyPromotion` function. And when the function case 2 run, it use the variable `menu` from case 1.

So, I update a bit of code by add `beforeEach` and set the variable `menu` inside and it's work !!

```
describe('Promotion: Discount By', () => {
let menu

// reset menu every round when run each test function
beforeEach(() => {
   menu = [{id:1, name: menu A}, {id:2, name: menu B}]
})

it('case 1', async () => { 
   var promotion = [{id:'P1', name:'promotion 1'}]
   var result = await applyPromotion(menu, promotion)
   expect(result['discountType']). toEqual('1')
});

it('case 2', async () => { 
   var promotion = [{id:'P2', name:'promotion 2'}]
   var result = await applyPromotion(menu, promotion)
   expect(result['discountType']). toEqual('2')
});
```

})